# The app crashes during login appium test

Tags: java, android, appium, mobile-application

I am writing the first test for login into my android app. I entered valid user's credentials (phone and password), then I entered the pin-code (1111) and then I confirmed this pin-code. But after the last `pincode.click()` my app crashes instead authentication process and appium test failed (but it does not crash when I log into the app manually).

I tried to use `Thread.sleep()` and `WebDriverWait`, but it does not help.

Why does the app crash and doesn't complete authentication and why does it not follow the code after `pincode.click()` perform?

**Here is a part of my code:**

```
@Test
public void SimpleTest() throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {

    Assert.assertNotNull(driver.getContext());

    WebElement phoneLoginField = driver.findElement(By.id("login_field"));
    phoneLoginField.click();
    phoneLoginField.sendKeys("9006400145");

    WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.id("password_field"));
    passwordField.click();
    passwordField.sendKeys("123456");

    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("submit_button"));
    loginButton.click();

    WebElement pincode = driver.findElement(By.id("pincode_one"));

    pincode.click();
    pincode.click();
    pincode.click();
    pincode.click();

    pincode.click();
    pincode.click();
    pincode.click();
    pincode.click();

    WebElement sidebarMenu = driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ImageButton"));
    sidebarMenu.click();
}
```

Comment: Why there are EIGHT `pincode.click()` calls ?

Comment: We must first to set pin-code on the app's keyboard, and we enter   "1" four times to get "1111". Then we must to confirm pin-code and repeat above input

Comment: Take a look at `adb` to debug your app. If your app crashed, chances are big you will find the cause in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

To investigate why an app crashed, you will need to look in the logs of the phone. You can use the Android debugger for this (adb). E.g. :

```
adb bugreport C:\Reports\MyBugReports
```

See https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report.html for more information on how to use `adb`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by selected another APP_ACTIVITY for  launch in DesiredCapabilities - SplashScreenActivity instead AuthenticatorActivity, it seems to be strange solution, but it works...